# MVVM Solution Architecture

Tags: mvvm, architecture, bind

I have a solution where my business logic is stored in one project and my UI is stored in another. I am using the MVVM design pattern to create an interface and I was thinking, would it be sensible and safe to place all my View-Models in another project?
Effectively, I would have 3 assemblies where the UI is the executable which binds controls data context to the View-Model class, which in turns binds to the Model class.

Please let me know

Tom

Answer (score 1):

started to write a long, detailed answer, then realized that I don't think it really matters;
As long as you keep a good separation of concerns, be it using different assemblies or a different folder within the same project, it doesn't matter that much.
The only scenario where it would matter is if you'd want to swap your view without swapping your view-model.
And even then, if your views and view-models are properly separated within the same assembly, it would be easy enough to refactor them out.

Answer (score 1):

An assembly is a unit of versioning.

So if you want to mix and match different versions of Models, ViewModels and Views, having them in separate assemblies might be a way of facilitating just that.

Answer (score 0):

It makes a lot of sense to place your `ViewModels` in a new project. I wouldn't say that it is the obvious thing to do, but in larger projects it would definitely be a valid option. I personally like to keep the `MainWindow ViewModel` in the main project, and then keep components in a separate project. Although, I usually design my programs around [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/), and have the ViewModel and View automatically loaded as plugins.